# Qt Set image to label reference variable

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I have some pictures in the resource file and their file names correspond to their `staffId`s. this is how I set the picture into my `QLabel` but nothing is shown.

```
QString staffId;
staffId=ui->lineEdit_staffID->text();
QPixmap managerPic(":/staff/\'"+staffId+"\'.jpg");
managerInterface.ui->label_mpic->setScaledContents(true);
managerInterface.ui->label_mpic->setPixmap(managerPic);
```

Comment: why are you putting `\'` characters before and after the `staffId` string? does your filename contain single-quote characters???

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Mike here, most probably the single quotes aren't part of your filenames. You can use the debugger to see what is passed to the `QPixmap` constructor, or put the name into a separate `QString` variable and write it to `qDebug()` to see what it contains.

In general you better use `QString::arg()` to build strings instead of concatenation; usually it's easier to read and understand:

```
QPixmap managerPic(QString(":/staff/\'%1\'.jpg").arg(staffId));
QPixmap managerPic(QString(":/staff/%1.jpg").arg(staffId));
```